# AMD modules with transitive dependencies

Tags: javascript, amd, bower

Suppose I want to create an AMD module that itself depends on some other AMD module.  Doesn't matter what, but to be tangible, suppose its some new kind of date-picker widget that depends on moment.js

So I setup a bower.json that looks something like this:

```
{
  "name": "sampleLib",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "description": "test",
  "main": "myControl.js",
  "moduleType": [
    "amd"
  ],
  "dependencies": {
    "moment": "~2.8.1"
  }
}
```

OK, cool.  No problem there.

My question is about how it gets consumed...  I see two options, neither of which I love:

#### Option One

Concat my code and moment.js into a unified script, and publish that.  Its easy for clients to consume since they only have to depend on my module.  In this scenario:

1. Is moment.js actually a devDependency, because my clients don't have to download it?
2. If a client depends on another module that *also* transitively depends on moment.js, is there any way around the client basically loading the library twice?

#### Option Two

Don't concat my code and keep moment.js declared as a dependency in bower.json.  So when a client `bower install`s my library, they'll also bring down moment.js.  Thats cool.  But the thing I worry about is namespacing...  Suppose I depend on moment as 'lib/moment', but the client is structured so that it just depends on moment as 'moment'?  At runtime, does my code fail because lib/moment isn't defined?  I worry this is too brittle, is there a way to harden this, besides good documentation?

#### TL;DR

What is the most robust way to publish AMD modules with dependencies?

Answer (score 1):

Option 1 - While concatenating is simpler for distributing your code, you hit on one of the issues with doing so - you run the risk of conflicts with other libraries. You also increase the size of your js library.

Option 2 - I don't think you're really referring to namespacing here, but rather the path of the module. Is that correct? RequireJS has a config block that you can change base paths and mappings that should solve the issue you're referring to. http://requirejs.org/docs/1.0/docs/api.html#config

So, in your case if you want to publish an AMD module and dependencies, I would still go with option 2.